# React Office UI Fabric - hoverCard Mode

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am very new to office UI fabric. I am trying to **show only compact card** for hoverCard. I have tried to provide `mode : ExpandingcardMode.compact` but it is not working.

How can I make it work?

```
render() 
{
    const expandingCardProps = {
        onRenderCompactCard: this.renderCompactCard,
        mode : ExpandingCardMode.compact,
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <HoverCard
                expandingCardProps={expandingCardProps}
                instantOpenOnClick={true}
                expandedCardOpenDelay={0}
                trapFocus={true}

                openHotKey={KeyCodes.enter}
            >
                <button> new York City</button>
            </HoverCard>
        </div>
    );
}
renderCompactCard = item => {
    return (
        <div >
            In the HoverCard
        </div>
    )
}
</div>
);
};
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what problems you are having.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question a bit to have the code format and indentation fixed. It demonstrates that you have unbalanced brackets. Assuming that your real code does not have this problem, could you please check and fix it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> `expandingCardProps`: Used along with `type` prop set to HoverCardType.expanding. Reference detail properties in ICardProps and IExpandingCardProps.

If you also include the type to `HoverCardType.expanding` on `<HoverCard>`, does it solve your issue?